# How to Mock $wpdb->prefix using WP_Mock and Mockery?

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

️ My Environment

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| PHP | 7.4 |
| WordPress | 6.2 |
| WP_Mock | 1.0 |
| PHPUnit | 9.6.11 |
| Mockery | 1.6.6 |

️ Code: TestCase

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use WP_Mock;
use Mockery;

class WPAB_Database_Service_Test extends TestCase
{
  /**
   * @test
   */
  public function migrate()
  {
    // ... some code ...

    $wpdb_mock = Mockery::mock('WPDB');

    $wpdb_mock
      ->allows('get_charset_collate')
      ->withNoArgs()
      ->andReturn('utf16_general_ci');

    $wpdb_mock->prefix = 'wpbb_';

    $result = $database_service->migrate(); // The function I want test

    $this->assertSame($result, 1);
  }
}
```

️ Code: Row issue of `database_service->migrate()`

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
```

Issue and expectation

After running the test and I have the following warning :

> `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Mockery_1__WPDB::$prefix in ...`

And the current test succeeded for unkown reason. May Mockery return empty string by default  (If someone got the answer)

**Does anyone know how to simulate/mock a specific property (static and non-static) with WP_Mock and/or Mockery ?**

I need to know the best way to avoid this type of warning.
Thank you in advance for your time ❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just miss the line bellow in my test..

```php
global $wpdb;
```